Azure DevOps YAML - can I trigger a job on another agent?
Currently my DevOps pipeline uses two servers to run things in parallel:
jobBuildAll on server 1:

build Debug version
run all unit tests

jobBuildAll on server 2:

build Release version
run static code analysis

It's a large Windows C++ project, each server is busy for over 8 hours - the debug build takes around 2, and the unit tests 6 hours, the release build 4 hours, with another 4 hours for the static code analysis.
I also have to run functional tests on a dedicated third server, they take around 6 hours.
What I would like to do is:

Publish the subset of artifacts required for the functional tests, as soon as they are built (1 hour)
make that trigger jobFunctionalTests on server 3, to run those tests in parallel with the unit tests on server 1, and the static analysis on server 2.

As far as I know there is no "official" way, is there any, however unofficial, to achieve the this?

Just out of curiosity, which kind of code are you building? Java, .NET, ...? How much time does it take for each component - generate the artifacts required for the functional tests, building the code, running the unit tests, running code analysis? It would be great if you could edit your question with these details. We might be able to help you if we have a bit more context.

Fair point, @rui-jarimba, edited the question accordingly.

Where are the artifacts required for the functional tests being generated? In the the debug build part?

The artifacts required for the functional tests are executables, and DLLs generated during the debug build, yes.


The artifacts required for the functional tests are executables, and DLLs generated during the debug build.

Your debug build takes around 2 hours, but the artifacts required for the functional tests are built in 1 hour which is less.
Hence, if you would like to publish artifacts and trigger function test job as soon as they are built, you could consider below options:

If possible, split the debug build task to two or more jobs, if your artifacts are generated in job1, then function test job are dependsOn the job1. Once artifacts are generated when job1 complete, the function test job will start.

The other option is you can consider to put the functional tests in a new pipeline. As you are using local agent, you can generate artifacts to a new folder wher the new pipeline is monitoring, the change will trigger the function test pipeline.

Similar as option2, you can generate the artifact in specific stage in 1st build, and in new pipeline, use Resource pipeline completion trigger to monitor on the stage, once it's completed, trigger the function test pipeline.



Thanks, @wade-zhou-msft, especially option 2 and 3 sounds very promising. If I use a new pipeline for the functional tests, can I then get the result (pipeline succeeded or not) as an input in the main pipeline? Only if both unit tests and functional tests (running on different servers/agents) have succeeded, I want to move to deployment.

Since you are using local agents, you can put the result to a file at the pipeline end. Add a step to read the file content to determine to run deployment or not.

To answer my own question, as it might help someone with a similar problem:
On Azure DevOps Server I'm building a large project. The debug build and unit tests run one server1, the release build and static code analysis on server2.
Each server is busy for hours, the actual builds for about half of the time on each server.
After the debug build on server1 is finished, and before the unit tests start, I want to trigger functional tests on server3, they run for hours as well.
Of course I could split the jobs, to know when the build has finished, but then the unit tests could/would be on another agent directory, and I would have a huge amount of files to publish and download.
So the task was to start a job from within another job. My solution, not perfect, but working:
The job FunctionalTests is startet in parallel with the two build jobs.
When the actual build on server1 is finished, it publishes the artifacts, writes a trigger file to server3, and runs all unit tests.
The job on server3 just waits until the trigger file is found, then downloads the build artifacts, and runs the functional tests with the new files.
stages:
  - stage: stageBuildWithoutAnalysis
    #      =========================
    displayName: 'Build, no analysis'
    pool:
      demands: server1
    jobs:
    - template: /Jobs/jobBuild-All.yml
      parameters:
        configuration: Debug
        staticAnalysis: false

  - stage: stageBuildWithAnalysis
    #      ===================
    displayName: 'Build with static analysis'
    dependsOn: []
    pool:
      demands: server2
    jobs:
    - template: /Jobs/jobBuild-All.yml
      parameters:
        configuration: Release
        staticAnalysis: true

  - stage: stageFunctionalTests
    #      ====================
    displayName: 'Functional Tests (after build)'
    dependsOn: []
    pool:
      demands: server3
    condition: ${{ parameters.runFunctionalTests }}
    jobs:
    - job: jobFunctionalTests
      steps:
      - checkout: none

      - script: del C:\trigger.txt

      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Wait for build to complete'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |      
            While (!(Test-Path C:\trigger.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
            {
              Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
              # Do until trigger file has been created by build job
            }
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |      
            echo Running functional tests!

  - stage: stageDeploy
    #      ===========
    displayName: 'Deployment/Reports'
    dependsOn: 
    - stageBuildWithoutAnalysis
    - stageBuildWithAnalysis
    - stageFunctionalTests
    pool:
      demands: server1
    jobs:
      - template: /Stages/stageDeploy.yml

It works quite nicely, with control over the stages for a manual run:

